# CSS selector regex anything in between

Tags: regex, css, css-selectors

I'm creating the following elements:

```
    .dh-tl-tl {}
    .dh-tl-tr {}
    .dh-tl-br {}
    .dh-tl-bl {}

    .dh-tr-tl {}
    ...

    .dh-br-tl {}
    ...

    .dh-bl-tl {}
    ...
```

Is there a way I could get a CSS selector to get the 4 items in each group?

e.g.

```
    [class=(?<=.dh-)(.*)(?=-bl)] {}
```

Comment: I believe this is possible. What is the expected output

Comment: I'd like to select all the `.dh-*-tl`, for example, or `.dh-*-br`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the `^=` ('starts with') and `$=` ('ends with') attribute selectors.

```
[class^="dh-"][class$="-bl"]{}
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are trying to select all elements whose class name begins with an expression and also ends with another expression.

There are two CSS selectors that can be used for this

- `[attribute*="value"]` - Attribute begins with selector
- `[attribute$="value"]` - Attribute ends with selector

```css
[class^="dh-"][class$="-tl"] { color: red; }
[class^="dh"][class$="-tr"] { color: orange; }
[class^="dh"][class$="-bl"] { color: green; }
[class^="dh"][class$="-br"] { color: blue; }
```

```html
<p class="dh-tl-tl">This is group 1, it is colored red</p>
<p class="dh-tl-tr">This is group 2, it is colored orange</p>
<p class="dh-tl-bl">This is group 3, it is colored green</p>
<p class="dh-tl-br">This is group 4, it is colored blue</p>

<p class="dh-tr-tl">This is group 1, it is colored red</p>
<p class="dh-tr-tr">This is group 2, it is colored orange</p>
<p class="dh-tr-bl">This is group 3, it is colored green</p>
<p class="dh-tr-br">This is group 4, it is colored blue</p>

<p class="dh-bl-tl">This is group 1, it is colored red</p>
<p class="dh-bl-tr">This is group 2, it is colored orange</p>
<p class="dh-bl-bl">This is group 3, it is colored green</p>
<p class="dh-bl-br">This is group 4, it is colored blue</p>

<p class="dh-br-tl">This is group 1, it is colored red</p>
<p class="dh-br-tr">This is group 2, it is colored orange</p>
<p class="dh-br-bl">This is group 3, it is colored green</p>
<p class="dh-br-br">This is group 4, it is colored blue</p>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp

Answer (score 1):

## use this

if element like div then use and class begin 'dh-', you can use.

```
div[class*='dh-']
```